# Deserializing enum in Java

Tags: java, serialization, enums, singleton, deserialization

I can see abstract class enum has implementation of readObject() method of marker interface Serializable which throws InvalidObjectException.

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
        throw new InvalidObjectException("can't deserialize enum");
}

private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException {
        throw new InvalidObjectException("can't deserialize enum");
}
```

My understanding from this is when deserializing an enum we can get InvalidObjectException.
But I am able to deserialize my enum.

As per my understanding if readResolve() method implementation is provided then jvm calls this method during deserializing so technically i should get an error but instead I am getting object.

my code:

```
enum Person50{
    OBJECT;
}
private static void serializationSingletonEnum() throws Exception{
        Person50 p50 = Person50.OBJECT;
        System.out.println("hashCode 1:" +p50.hashCode());

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("enumFile.ser"));
        oos.writeObject(p50);
        oos.close();

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("enumFile.ser"));
        Person50 p15 = (Person50)ois.readObject();
        System.out.println("hashCode after:" +p15.hashCode());
}
```

Output:

```
hashCode 1:1435804085
hashCode after:1435804085
```

I might be committing some silly mistake I think so or my understanding about serialization invocation might be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it works is that the Enum serialization process ignores readObject() implementation

As per [official documentaion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/serialization/serial-arch.html)

> 1.12 Serialization of Enum Constants Enum constants are serialized differently than ordinary serializable or externalizable objects. The
> serialized form of an enum constant consists solely of its name; field
> values of the constant are not present in the form. To serialize an
> enum constant, ObjectOutputStream writes the value returned by the
> enum constant's name method. To deserialize an enum constant,
> ObjectInputStream reads the constant name from the stream; the
> deserialized constant is then obtained by calling the
> java.lang.Enum.valueOf method, passing the constant's enum type along
> with the received constant name as arguments. Like other serializable
> or externalizable objects, enum constants can function as the targets
> of back references appearing subsequently in the serialization stream.
>
> The process by which enum constants are serialized cannot be
> customized: any class-specific writeObject, readObject,
> readObjectNoData, writeReplace, and readResolve methods defined by
> enum types are ignored during serialization and deserialization.
> Similarly, any serialPersistentFields or serialVersionUID field
> declarations are also ignored--all enum types have a fixed
> serialVersionUID of 0L. Documenting serializable fields and data for
> enum types is unnecessary, since there is no variation in the type of
> data sent.